# KendoUI DropDownList - when "New..." is selected, display text box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, knockout-kendo

I have a list of items in a KendoUI DropDownList. It is generated using Razor syntax

What I want to do:

- If user does not find what he/she is looking for from list, he/she selects "New..."(A static value)
- a hidden text-field should display allowing them to add the new value
- the new value should be posted back to a controller method (WIP)

What I figured:

- Get data
- statically add the "New" option

This works well so far:

- It fetches the data from a controller action method and displays the list as expected
- I can bind it to two events: "Change" and "DataBound"

Problem:

I am using jQuery's "ready" method to add the static value called "New..". It is duplicating this value. I think it is an infinite loop.

So am stuck at this point

In Partial view:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(model => model.ClientType)
                              .DataSource(ds => ds.Read(read => read.Action("FetchAllClientTypes", "ClientType")))
                              .DataTextField("Description")
                              .DataValueField("Id")
                              .AutoBind(true)
                              .Events(e =>
                               {
                                   e.Change("onClientTypeChange").DataBound("onClientTypeDataBound");
                               })
                              .ToClientTemplate()
                      )
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ClientType)
```

Javascript:

```
/*When dropdown is bound, add "New..."*/
/* Duplicates "New". Appears to be infinite. */
function onClientTypeDataBound() {
    var clientTypesDropDownList = $('#ClientType').data('kendoDropDownList');
    clientTypesDropDownList.dataSource.add({ Description: 'New...', value: '-1' });

};

/**Works**/
function onClientTypeChange() {

    alert('Testing On change');
};
```

Comment: Is New... a value in the dropdown?

Comment: It is the display text added to the dropdownlist. Its form value is -1.

Answer (score 0):

All that you described is support out-of-the-box by the ComboBox widget. If there is no such value in the items collection, then the value of the ComboBox becomes the text that the user typed. Take a closer look at the ComboBox widget [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/Beta/web/combobox/api.html) (more specifically use the getValue button when playing with different values).

Comment: Thanks. Am having a look at Combobox. Issue I have with it is that it is not obvious to the user that they are entering something new. It is as though they are editing or searching. So whilst I appreciate the answer, it does not solve the original requirement... unless there is some way that you know to have it behave as required or something close